# How to represent the Null class in Multilabel Classification with Convolutional Neural Nets?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I'm trying to label images with the various categories that they belong to with a convolutional neural net. For my problem, the image can be in a single category, multiple categories, or zero categories. Is it standard practice to set the zero category as all zeroes or should I add an additional null class neuron to the final layer?

As an example, let's say there are 5 categories (not including the null class). Currently, I'm representing that with [0,0,0,0,0]. The alternative is adding a null category, which would look like [0,0,0,0,0,1]. Won't there also be some additional unnecessary parameters in this second case or will this allow the model to perform better?

I've looked on Stackoverflow for similar questions, but they pertain to Multiclass Classification, which uses the Categorical Crossentropy with softmax output instead of Binary Crossentropy with Sigmoid output, so the obvious choice there is to add the null class (or to do thresholding).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the "null" category should be represented as just zeros. In the end multi-label classification is a set of C binary classification problems, where C is the number of classes, and if all C problems output "no class", then you get a vector of just zeros.

Comment: Thank you! I up'd/accept your answer, but I don't have enough rep for it to show up yet. I have a quick additional question if you can help! If one of my labels is a general version of the other classes, should I have both the general and the special class represented as 1's, or should I only light up the general version when the special class isn't present. As an example, let's say I'm labeling images of pizza toppings. Would it be best to have [Any Pizza Present, Pineapples, Ham] OR [Any Pizza w/o Pineapples or Ham, Pineapples, Ham] as my label. For Pineapple+Ham, this is [1,1,1] vs [0,1,1].

Comment: @Austin I am not sure what you are talking about, because you did accept the question, you can upvote/accept without any rep limits. About your question, the classes are independent, so the first case would only apply, the classes should know nothing about each other.

Comment: That was my hunch, but I wanted to be sure. I'm still somewhat new to Multilabel Classification. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

The model outputs a probability to each class, and we assign the input to the class which has the highest probability during prediction. The last layer is normally a softmax layer for multiclass classification and sigmoid for binary classification. Both of them squash the input into a range of 0 to 1. We can interpret them as probabilities. So no you cannot have all zeros as a one class (Null), because their values will sum up to 1 (probability). You have to define a new class for Null.

Comment: I have multiple sigmoids as my output, though. I currently get independent probabilities for each class with binary crossentropy. As an example, I get outputs like this [0.97, 0.11, 0.05, 0.35, 0.95] for an image with the label [1,0,0,0,1].

Comment: You are not considering the case of multi-label classification, which is not the same as multi-class classification.